# rails 4 - what wysiwyg offers image uploading based on user groups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, wysiwyg

Not sure the title explains what i'm trying to do or not.  Basically, i am building a wiki-like ruby on rails application.  I have model called `Page` that needs a WYSIWYG for the `content` data.  My application has many users that will be grouped by an `Organization` so each user will `belong_to` an `Organization`.  My only requirements are 1) it is a WYSIWYG that allows S3 image uploading and 2) When you click "upload image" you should be able to see all the images that have been uploaded by users **that belong to the same organization as you**.  I will need to store the images in a bucket in S3 like `<bucket_name>/<organization_id>/rest_of_image_path...`.  Hopefully this all makes sense.

Does anyone know of a wysiwyg editor that will do this?  If someone could point me in the right direction i'd be greatly appreciative!  Also, if this is not the appropriate place for this question to be please let me know and i'll move it.  Thanks!